# Keyboard resizing cuts a part of a button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have a constraint layout inside a scroll view, with "adjustResize" in AndroidManifest.xml, because i want my views to resize when the user taps on an edit text. The problem is that sometimes (almost randomly) when I tap on the edit text (so the keyboard opens) or when i exit from the keyboard (pressing back button) the button is cut. This is what happens:

[image]

This is my layout:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:theme="@style/EditTextStyleSendFunds"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView2"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.056"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:theme="@style/EditTextStyleSendFunds"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/editText3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText3" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:theme="@style/EditTextStyleSendFunds"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="31dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/spinner2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_qrcode_grey600_24dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/spinner2"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="68dp"
            android:layout_height="27dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/spinner2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText3" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_width="68dp"
            android:layout_height="27dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
            android:theme="@style/SpinnerSendFunds"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:theme="@style/SpinnerSendFunds"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/editText5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/spinner"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText5" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editText4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText4"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/add" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttons2"
            android:text="SEND"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/spinner5"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner5" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:text="Add Additional Data"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText4" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText4"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:theme="@style/EditTextStyleSendFunds"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView6"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView6"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_width="113dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:theme="@style/EditTextStyleSendFunds"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView7"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView7"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView7" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editText2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView6"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "almost randomly"? Does it happen with a particular `EditText`? Does the whole layout get adjusted at all when you open the keyboard or does every view stay in place? If you close the keyboard is the button still cut?

Comment: It happens with all the EditTexts. The loop is:
1) I tap on edit text, the button is not cut;
2) I close the keyboard, the button gets cut;
3) I open the edittext, the button remains cut;
4) I close the keyboard, the button returns normal.

Comment: Can you try constrainting the bottom of the button to the bottom of the parent (`app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`) and see if it helps?

Comment: now insted of cut the button the button is moved up, but even if the keyboard is not shown...